# Is (float)(1.2345f * 6.7809) more accurate than 1.2345f * 6.7809f?

Tags: c++

I have some blocks of code that do:

```
float total = <some float>;
double some_dbl = <some double>;

total *= some_dbl;
```

This elicits a compiler warning which I want to shut up, but I don't like turning off such warnings - instead, I would rather explicitly cast types as needed. Which got me thinking...is a `(float)(total * some_dbl)` more accurate than `total * (float)some_dbl`? Is it compiler or platform specific?

Better code example (linked below):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    double d_total = 1.2345678;
    float f_total = (float)d_total;
    double some_dbl = 6.7809123;

    double actual = (d_total * some_dbl);
    float no_cast = (float)(f_total * some_dbl);
    float with_cast = (float)(f_total * (float)some_dbl);

    cout << "actual:               " << setprecision(25) << actual << endl;
    cout << "no_cast:              " << setprecision(25) << no_cast << endl;
    cout << "with_cast:            " << setprecision(25) << with_cast << endl;
    cout << "no_cast, nextafter:   " << setprecision(25) << nextafter(no_cast, 500.0f) << endl;

    cout << endl;

    cout << "Diff no_cast:   " << setprecision(25) << actual - no_cast << endl;
    cout << "Diff with_cast: " << setprecision(25) << with_cast - actual << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Edit:**
So, I gave this a shot. With the examples I tried, I did find one quickly where `total * (float)(some_dbl)` appears to be *more* accurate. I assume this isn't going to always be the case, but is instead luck of the draw, or the compiler is truncating doubles to get to float, rather than rounding, causing potentially worse results.  See: http://ideone.com/sRXj1z

**Edit 2:** I confirmed using `std::nextafter` that `(float)(total * some_dbl)` is returning the truncated value, and updated the linked code. It is quite surprising: if the compiler in this case is always truncating doubles, than you can say `(float)some_dbl <= some_dbl`, which then implies `with_cast <= no_cast`. However, this is *not* the case! `with_cast` is not only greater than `no_cast`, but it is closer to the actual value as well, which is kinda surprising, given that we are discarding information before the multiplication occurs.

Comment: `(float)(total * some_dbl)` should be more accurate because, well, math... and that's true for every language.

Comment: gcc has a flag `-ffast-math` in which it is no longer bound by some of the the strictures that the standard places on floating point; it'd be interesting to see if that affects your result

Comment: Another "strange" thing you may find is that using `1.2345678f` in your source gives a different result to `(double)1.2345678` - the rounding at runtime may occur differently to the rounding at compile-time.

Comment: @MattMcNabb, updated a bit to try and handle; not sure what tricks the compiler is doing, so maybe playing with compile flags will change this behavior.

Comment: Of course they're different. The latter version entails only single-precision arithmetic, while the former implies a promotion to double-precision of the left operand of the multiplication, followed by a demotion `(cast)`. This is perfectly in line with the C Standard's _6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions_, which states in part: _Otherwise, if the corresponding real type of either operand is double, the other operand is converted, without change of type domain, to a type whose corresponding real type is double._ And rounding being what it is, an over-precise result may round differently.

Comment: It depends to your values what method is closer. Here is another example http://ideone.com/xC8gYA.

Answer (score 10):

It will make a difference depending on the size of the numbers involved, because `double` is not just about more precision but can also hold numbers larger than `float`. Here's a sample that will show one such instance:

```
double d = FLT_MAX * 2.0;
float f = 1.0f / FLT_MAX;

printf("%f\n", d * f);
printf("%f\n", (float)d * f);
printf("%f\n", (float)(d * f));
```

And the output:

```
2.000000
inf
2.000000
```

This happens because while `float` can obviously hold the *result* of the computation -- `2.0`, it can not hold the intermediate value of `FLT_MAX * 2.0`

Comment: This makes sense to me, but doesn't explain the behavior in the above with regards to rounding. Namely, why would `with_cast` be more accurate than `no_cast`? (see edit 2 above)

Answer (score 2):

If you do an operation then the compiler converts the variables into the biggest datatype of that operation. Here it is double. In my opinion the operation: (float)(var1f * var2) has more accuracy.

Comment: i'm not understanding your answer but it's opinion. make it a comment please.

Comment: I can't do a comment.

Comment: @NoIdeaForName This is no opinion - this is fact. See my comment below OP's post, and examine the C Standard's Usual Arithmetic Conversions at section _6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions_.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist I think he meant that *in his opinion*, the answer was not understandable.

Comment: This is an incorrect use of of "opinion", rather this is an "AFAIK", which also happens to be true.

Answer (score 1):

I tested it and they aren't equal. The result of the below is `true`. http://codepad.org/3GytxbFK

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  double a = 1.0/7;
  float b = 6.0f;
  float c = 6.0f;
  b = b * (float)a;
  c = (float)((double)c * a);
  cout << (b-c != 0.0f) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

This leads me to reason: The cast from the result of the multiplication expressed as a `double` to a `float` will have a better chance to round. Some bits can fall off the end with the `float` multiplication that would have been correctly accounted for when the multiplication is carried out on `double`s then casted to `float`.

BTW, I chose 1/7*6 because it repeats in binary.

**Edit:** Upon research, it seems the rounding should be the same for both conversion from double to float and for multiplication of floats, at least in an implementation conforming to IEEE 754. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Rounding_modes

Comment: you should also check `b-c` before you do the multiplications, and see which of those two results is closer to zero

Comment: @MattMcNabb This is what I did with my edit example; Tyler's logic is what I suspected as well, but I also thought it possible that mathematically there wouldn't be a difference. Clearly there is!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the figures from your code dump, two adjacent possible values of `float` are:

```
        d1 =  8.37149524...
        d2 =  8.37149620...
```

The result of doing the multiplication in double precision is:

```
              8.37149598...
```

which is in between those two, of course.  Converting this result to `float` is *implementation-defined* as to whether it "rounds" up or down.  In your code results, the conversion has selected `d1`, which is permitted, even though it is not the closest. The mixed-precision multiplication ended up with `d2`.

So we can conclude, somewhat unintuitively, that doing a calculation of doubles in double precision and then converting to `float` is in some cases less accurate than doing it entirely in `float` precision!